# Setting up MCU headers

Tags: c, macros, cpu-registers

I've been having some trouble setting up my libraries.

I'm looking forward to get a macro like PINSEL(P,N) with P as the number of the GPIO port and also N as the number of the pin in the port.

```
#ifndef uint32_t
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
#endif

#ifndef __RW
#define __RW volatile
#endif
#ifndef __R
#define __R volatile const
#endif

typedef union{
     struct {
         uint32_t PINSELP4:2;
     } PINSELP4[16];
    struct{
        __RW uint32_t PINSEL9_;
    };
    struct{
        __RW uint32_t RES1_:24;
        __RW uint32_t PINSELP4_28_:2;
        __RW uint32_t PINSELP4_29_:2;
        __RW uint32_t RES2_:4;
    };
}PINSELP4_t;

#define PINSELP4_ ((PINSELP4_t *)(0x4002C024))
#define PINSELP4(N) PINSELP4_->PINSELP4_[N]->PINSELP4
#define PINSEL9 PINSELP4_->PINSEL9_
#define PINSELP4_28 PINSELP4_->PINSELP4_28_
#define PINSELP4_29 PINSELP4_->PINSELP4_29_
```

The example above shows the shorter struct of the 5 I've defined.

so then I've defined this two macros

```
#define PINSEL__(N)[] {PINSELP0(N),PINSELP1(N),PINSELP2(N),PINSELP3(N),PINSELP4(N)}
#define PINSEL(P,N) PINSEL__(N)[P]
```

I'm trying to make an "array of macros" for this to work. I'ts the only way I've figured it out. It still doesn't work. When I call the macro, I get

```
../src/../Includes/PINSEL_LPC1769.h:246:20: error: expected expression before '[' token
#define PINSEL__(N)[]={PINSELP0(N),PINSELP1(N),PINSELP2(N),PINSELP3(N),PINSELP4(N)}
                    ^
```

as error.

I'm trying to make a really complete down layer so I can get a much clearer app layer. So if there's another way of doing this, I'll be listening.

Thank you all!

Comment: Learn C first then reinvent the wheel. Everything is wrong in this and even if you get it compiled, it will not work. Use  CMSIS and forget about your "libraries".

Comment: You were so helpful and useful! Anyway, it worked. I think that you should learn c, gordo virgen